# Ways to connect to Linux, Windows and Mac systems

Tags: linux, ssh, windows, macos

This question is regarding ways to connect to Linux, Windows and Mac systems. I read that using SSH you can connect to a Linux PC (imagine that my public key is in the authorized_keys on the Linux PC). For windows I can create a share and access the contents. This might appear a bit silly to ask but

1) can't I SSH into a Windows PC ?

2) how do I access a Mac PC ? Do I use SSH to do so ?

3) If I am on Linux and I want to SSH into windows, is it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

1. You can SSH in to a Windows machine. You need to install the ssh server in it.
   You can install Openssh server on Windows 10 and Windows Server 2019 as described in this official document from Microsoft - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse. 
   After installing the Openssh server in the Windows machine and configure it, you can ssh in to the Windows machine.
2. You can access a Mac machine with SSH. About having remote ssh access to a machine with Mac OS, it is answered here - https://superuser.com/questions/104929/how-do-you-run-a-ssh-server-on-mac-os-x
3. Yes, it is possible.